# Nginx Docker and Redirecting Issue

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Sorry for the post as I know this must be basic but my goal is to type `hostname` and get redirected to hostname:8080 (adminer instance).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        hostname: adminer
        container_name: adminer
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        restart: always
    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine    
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
        depends_on:
          - adminer
```

nginx.conf

```
events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
         server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
        }
}
```

Currently, if I enter `localhost`, it just presents me with the default Nginx page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try it `proxy_pass          http://adminer:8080/;`

Comment: Same issue, I tried that already :(

Comment: try `proxy_pass          http://172.17.0.1:8080/;`

Comment: Still sending me to nginx default page. Can't understand what am I missing..

Comment: how is when you access `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Same issue. Here is the log from the compose:

`nginx               | 2020/11/06 03:18:11 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"`

Comment: You are using docker-compose.yml -> `environment` as if it were `volume`. (So your nginx.conf is likely never even used)

Comment: Omg.. You are right.. I changed it to `volumes`. Now I get "502 Bad Gateway"

Comment: I got it! I had to change it to `http://172.17.0.1:8080/;` Could anyone point out why this is the address and not localhost?

Comment: Both `http://172.17.0.1:8080/;` and `http://adminer:8080/;` works. Thanks to @ippi and @thanh-nguyen-van

Comment: docker-compose adds both containers to an internal network and manages a DNS service to resolve container names to the relevent IP addresses on this internal network. The first sentence in the documentation here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ - summarises this.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Is it possible to resolve `http://adminer.localhost` to `http://localhost:8080`? If so, would I have to change the `/etc/hosts` on the nginx container? I would like to add other apps to `app.localhost` for convenience. Or perhaps `networks:` allow for these aliases.